# update a list of items with other list with css is possible?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make it so when I click on the href "+ links", my list of links updates to my other list of links.

Is it possible to do this using only html and css? I am looking for documentation on this but I haven't find anything, so I guess I'm looking for a little help.

```
  <footer id="footer-container">
       <section id="footer1">

           <ul>
              <h1>Links</h1>
              <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"> + links </a></li>
           </ul>

           <ul>         
              <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">+ links</a></li>
           </ul>

        </section>
    </footer>
```

Comment: **NO** you cannot tweak your DOM using CSS

Comment: Ah ok, I didnt know, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: Not Possible.

CSS & HTML cannot change state via clicks. You can achieve changing which list is shown when the user hovers over something, but you cannot do this when a user clicks something.

EDIT: To respond to your comment about jQuery:

```
$('#myID').click(function{

    Put your changes here. The above line will trigger when a user clicks on an element with the id of myID.

    You could accomplish the menu change by hiding and showing:

    $('ul#firstList').hide();

    $('ul#secondList').show();

    You'll need to use an if/else statement to see which list is currently visible though.

});
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, i didnt have found that information! So I´ll try to find a way with jquery!